# ashx page opens in excel instead of document retrieved

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have links that call a javascript function "GetDocument"  which passes the ID of the link that the user wants to retrieve to an ashx page which than retrieves the document from a database and writes it back to the users browser if it's a PDF or opens the appropriate program if it's something else.  These could be PDF's, XLS, DOCX.... etc..  When the user clicks a link that is a PDF everything work just fine and the PDF is opened within the browser.  When the user opens anything else though, lets say for example an xlsx excel opens a garbage file with the name of the .ashx page.   No errors occur and everything works with PDF.  I'm kind of at a loss.

Here is the javascript

```
function GetDocument(id) {
    spl1.loadPage('RightContent', 'FrmDocHandler.ashx?ID=' + id);
}
```

Here is the .ashx page

```
Public Class FrmDocHandler
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim sID As String = context.Request.QueryString("id")

        Dim fileName As String = String.Empty
        Dim fileType As String = String.Empty
        Dim bytes() As Byte

        bytes = Get_Blob(fileName, fileType, sSql_GetDocument(sID))
        context.Response.Clear()
        'clear the content of the browser
        context.Response.ClearContent()
        context.Response.ClearHeaders()
        context.Response.Buffer = True

        'I tried both of these add header and the same result
        'context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName)

        context.Response.ContentType = GetMIMEType(fileType)

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)


    End Sub
```

MIME Types returned by GetMIMEType

```
Public Const g_MIME_DOC As String = "application/msword"
    Public Const g_MIME_DOCX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    Public Const g_MIME_DOT As String = "application/msword"
    Public Const g_MIME_DOTX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"
    Public Const g_MIME_HTM As String = "text/html"
    Public Const g_MIME_HTML As String = "text/html"
    Public Const g_MIME_JPEG As String = "image/jpeg"
    Public Const g_MIME_PDF As String = "application/pdf"
    Public Const g_MIME_PPSX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"
    Public Const g_MIME_PPT As String = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
    Public Const g_MIME_PPTX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
    Public Const g_MIME_XLS As String = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Public Const g_MIME_XLSX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Public Const g_MIME_XLTX As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"
    Public Const g_MIME_XML As String = "application/rss+xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

The line which is probably causing the file to be opened in Excel is the following:

`context.Response.ContentType = GetMIMEType(fileType)`

A couple of things you can do:

1. Check to see what MIME type is being returned by `GetMIMEType`, and ensure its a PDF related one (`application/pdf`) rather than an Excel related one (`application/vnd.ms-excel`)
2. Check on the browser end to see what application is set to handle the mime type and/or file extension that you are sending from the server

Comment: Hi.  When a user selects a link that is a PDF it works correctly.  When a user selects a link that points to anything but a PDF is when it fails.  GetMIMEType is just a small function that returns the MIME Type based on the file extension.  I've added the MIME types above